# Как избавиться от лишних строк в цикле django?

Tags: python, django, циклы, шаблоны

Я пытаюсь вывести информацию в цикле в шаблоне django. Например так:

```
{% for pr in products %}<h5 class="order_all">
    {% if item.product|make_list == pr.product_title|make_list %}
    <img src="{{pr.product_img.url}}" width="70" alt="">
     &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ item.product }} ({{ item.quantity }} шт.){% endif %}</h5>
{% endfor %}
```

Но в браузере появляются лишние (пустые) теги . Как на картинке ниже.

[image: в браузере]

Как можно от этого избавиться?

Comment: Очевидно, переместить тег внутрь if, не?

Answer (score 3):

Я переделал код. Заключил цикл внутрь тега h5. Теперь все нормально.

```
<h5 class="order_all">
  {% for pr in products %}
      {% if item.product|make_list == pr.product_title|make_list %}
        <img src="{{pr.product_img.url}}" width="70" alt="">
 &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ item.product }} ({{ item.quantity }} шт.){% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</h5>
```

Answer (score 1):

h5 вынести за цикл for и все заработает

Answer (score 0):

Надо тег h5 (вместе с закрывающим) поместить внутрь if.